# How to pass the updated text by CommandParameter in TextChagned event?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

This is an interesting case. I use MVVMLight to catch the event TextChagned of a textbox and pass it to a command in ViewModel and somehow the text value passed by CommandParameter is still the old text before the update. 
Anyone knows how to get the new text?

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=TextChangedCommand}" 
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text,ElementName=myTextBox}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="352,214,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>




</Grid>
```

[image]

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ////if (IsInDesignMode)
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs "for real"
        ////}
    }

    private RelayCommand<string> _textChangedCommand;

    public RelayCommand<string> TextChangedCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            if (this._textChangedCommand == null)
            {
                this._textChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(this.TextChanged);
            }
            return this._textChangedCommand; 
        }
    }

    private void TextChanged(string input)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(input);
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you post the C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was digging into the code of MVVM Light and in EventToCommand.cs's Invoke method it seems that the parameter still has its old value. I didn't look further, but maybe this is a bug in MVVM.

There is a workaround you can do though.

Create a new class implementing `IEventArgsConverter`, something similar to this:

```
public class TextChangedEventArgsConverter : IEventArgsConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, object parameter)
    {
        var textChangedEventArgs = (TextChangedEventArgs) value;
        return ((TextBox) textChangedEventArgs.Source).Text;
    }
}
```

Add it to the `Resources` collection of your `Window` or `ResourceDictionary` where you have the `EventToCommand` that's not working.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <textChanged:TextChangedEventArgsConverter x:Key="TextChangedEventArgsConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And change the `EventToCommand` to the following:

```
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=TextChangedCommand}" 
                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource TextChangedEventArgsConverter}" />
```

So the specified `EventArgsConverter` will receive the actual `TextChangedEventArgs` and will extract the `Text` itself, which will be the correct value.

With these changes, I was able to achieve what you are looking for.

[image: Desired result]

By the way: don't use `CommandParameter` and `PassEventArgsToCommand="True"` at the same time. As the [documentation](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/a597306e-b5b4-40ce-c7a3-be77038db171.htm) says, if you are setting `PassEventArgsToCommand` to true, the type parameter of your `RelayCommand` should be the event argument type of the event which is `TextChangedEventArgs` in this case.

Comment: Thank you! When I was waiting for the help, I did the same thing. Instead, I put the TextBox in the CommandParameter as well as code read the TextBox=>Text property and it worked. Weird!

Comment: Thank you. This directed me to use a converter to solve the mouse double click issue with list box